# Find ALL the prerequisites for a given course

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have the following tables:

**COURSE_PREREQUISITES**

```
+----------+-------------------------+
| course_id | prerequisite_course_id |
+-----------+------------------------+
|        2  |                   1    |
+-----------+------------------------+
|        3  |                   2    |
+-----------+------------------------+  
|        3  |                   5    |
+-----------+------------------------+
|        4  |                   3    |
+-----------+------------------------+
|        6  |                   4    |
+-----------+------------------------+
```

**My question is:** How can I obtain all the course ids a student needs to take before he can take `course id` 6?

**Intended Answer:** I should obtain the `course id` of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

**Attempts Made:** I have tried selecting the `prerequisite_course_id` of the intended final `course id` 6, and nesting it within other select statements in order to obtain the full list of `prerequisite_course_id`, but I am stuck at implementing it, and I do not think this is a viable solution as well.

`SELECT prerequisite_course_id FROM course_prerequisites WHERE course_id = 6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select prerequisite_course_id
      from course_prerequisites
      where course_id = 6
      union all
      select cp.prerequisite_course_id
      from cte join
           course_prerequisites cp
           on cte.prerequisite_course_id = cp.course_id
    )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1fd39dd387a9954b8d0f87a4bf6b6170) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without a recursive query? Since I have not been taught that yet in my course

Comment: @JustAPerson . . . You would need to have a fixed number of joins -- like five in this case.  And the solution would not be generalizable.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select prerequisite_course_id from course_prerequisites where course_id = 6
    union all
    select cr.prerequisite_course_id
    from cte ct
    inner join course_prerequisites cr on cr.course_id = ct.prerequisite_course_id
)
select * from cte
```